# Python Beautifulsoup img tag parsing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, image

I am using beautifulsoup to parse all img tags which is present in 'www.youtube.com'

The code is

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
tags=soup.findAll('img')
```

But am not getting all img tags.The getting img tags are invalid also.

The img tags which i got after parsing is different from the page source img tags. Some attributes are missing.

I need to get all video img tags in youtube.com

Please help

Answer (score 6):

Seems to work when I try it here

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
tags=soup.findAll('img')
print "\n".join(set(tag['src'] for tag in tags))
```

Produces this which looks OK to me

```
http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/D9Zg67r9q9g/market_thumb.jpg?v=723c8e
http://s.ytimg.com/yt/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif
//s.ytimg.com/yt/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif
/gen_204?a=fvhr&v=mha7pAOfqt4&nocache=1337083207.97
http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/fNs8mf2OdkU/market_thumb.jpg?v=4f85544b
http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/CkQFjyZCq4M/market_thumb.jpg?v=4f95762c
http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/fzD5gAecqdM/market_thumb.jpg?v=b0cabf
http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/2M3pb2_R2Ng/market_thumb.jpg?v=4f0d95fa
//i2.ytimg.com/vi/mha7pAOfqt4/hqdefault.jpg
```

Comment: I tried the same but most of the src is same and most of the img tags are missing.

Comment: Yes for me, it only shows the first image source, not all :-(

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar problem. I couldn't find all images. So here is the piece of code that will give you any attribute value of an image tag.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BSHTML
import urllib2
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/')
soup = BSHTML(page)
images = soup.findAll('img')
for image in images:
    #print image source
    print image['src']
    #print alternate text
    print image['alt']
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly using `soup.findAll(name='img')` worked for me, and I don't appear to be missing anything from the page.

Comment: `soup.findAll(name='img')` returning same result.i tried to display it in an html page it displays nothing.

Comment: If you print out the result from `urllib2.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/')` is there actually anything to be displayed ?

Comment: i printed it the img tags are printed with some invalid src. and all img tags are not fetching.

Comment: how about video tags?\

Answer (score 0):

```
def grabimagetags():
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
tags = soup.findAll('img')
list.extend(set(tag['src'] for tag in tags))


return list
```

grabimagetags()

i would only make this change so that you can pass the list of img tags

Answer (score 0):

in my case some images didn't contain `src`.

so i did this to avoid `keyError` exception:

```
art_imgs = set(img['src'] for img in article.find_all('img') if img.has_attr('src'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, req
url = 'https://www.youtube.com'
html = req.get(url)
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
imgs = doc.listImg(url = url)
print([img.url for img in imgs])

imgs = doc.selects('img')
for img in imgs:
  print (img)
  print (doc.absoluteUrl(url,img.src))
```