# Failed to read HTML page using Python requests

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a simple page containing an image. I want to save the image locally. So I am using `BeauitfulSoup` to scrape the `src`. Following is my code :

```
    def getImage(url):

        page = requests.get(url).text
        #print(page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
        #print(soup)

        img = soup.find(name='img')

        if img is not None:
            #img = img.get('src')
            print(img.attrs)
```

If I print `page`, this is [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDn0c.png) I will get.
I also checked if the page is HTML, it says **it is not**. But I don't know what other type in this case.
I also tried to use different parser such as `lxml` and `html5lib`.

This is the HTML page which I copied directly :

```
<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.1">
<title>SOMETHING TITLE</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; background: #0e0e0e;">
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;cursor: zoom-in;" src="http:<WHATEVER>" width="500" height="279">
</body></html>
```

Is the page encrypted? This should be a straightforward scraping :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute in your html with the name 'img'. You could add a name (i.e.

```
 <img name='myImage' style='-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;cursor: zoom-in; src='http:<WHATEVER>'>
```

and then you can use

```
 img = soup.find(name='myImage')
```

but if you can't change the HTML, you could do something like this:

```
   images = soup.findAll('img')
   for image in images:
     # do whatever
```

Comment: The problem is before the code can reach `bs4` part, `requests` failed to read it as HTML. Instead it gave out different unknown format which I do not know what. See the link attchment. I can't edit the HTML btw.

Comment: Try the tips here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600079/python-beautifulsoup-img-tag-parsing

Comment: I found the cause of the issue. The page content type is `image/png`. So I do not need to take the high road using `bs4`. Instead I can directly download the image locally from `requests`. Thank you btw!